# Accented characters in Android XML

Tags: android, xml, string

i am developping a multi-lingual android app but i am unable to display the special caracters (ex : é or è). I tried to replace the caracters with their reference (&eacute) but it says "The entity &eacute was referenced, but not declared".

XML with special caracters  :

```
<string name="welcomeMsg1">Cette application a été conçu à fin de vous guider.</string>
```

When i use the above xml file, the special caracters are not displayed. So i replace the special caracters with their corresponding references.

XML with references :

```
<string name="welcomeMsg1">Cette application a &eacute;t&eacute; con&ccedil;u &aacute; fin de vous guider.</string>
```

The code above generates an error.

I couldn't find a solution so if someone can help i will be very grateful. Thank you

Comment: Please post the error.  Thanks.

Comment: The entity "eacute" was referenced, but not declared

Comment: That sounds like an encoding issue, are you declaring your encoding in your xml file?

Comment: Yes i start the xml file with this code  : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: Is the XML file itself encoded as UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions.  The first one requires you to create a DTD for your xml documents and declare `<!ENTITY>` types in the DTD.  You can google that.

The second solution is pretty nifty, but I don't know if it will work.  The HTML specification has a entity types declaration that should suffice.  I found this at:

[&eacute;=é: need to show as it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103554/eacute-%C3%A9-need-to-show-as-it-is)

```
String modString = Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml((String) yourstring).toString());
```

According to the post, the above code should give you a styled string with your characters added.

HTML Entity Listing
http://help.dottoro.com/lausooxp.php

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. But the problem was not with encoding or Entity declaration. I was using a custom font to display the text and it doesn't support the special caracters. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the accented characters in strings.xml with their unicode value.

For example, instead of writing `ó` you would write `\u00f3`